# How do I copy a Go string to a C char * via CGO in golang?

Tags: go, cgo

I want to copy a Go string into a char * via CGO.

Am I allowed to do this something like this?

```
func copy_string(cstr *C.char) {

    str := "foo"
    C.GoString(cstr) = str

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) you need to use the C.CString function to convert a Go string to a C string:

```
cstr = C.CString(str)
```

Be aware that C.CString function allocates the memory for you, but won't release it, so it is your responsability to freed the memory with a call like:

```
C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr))
```

Comment: better with `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr))` go will call when function returns

Answer (score 4):

using
`cstr = C.CString(str)`
did not work for me, so I opted for something I saw directy on [CGO library](https://github.com/chai2010/cgo/blob/master/char.go): `C.strcpy((*C.char)(cstr), (*C.char)(C.CString(str)))`

Comment: What about it didn't work?