# Access the raw bytes of a string

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to call a C function that expects a C string (`char*`) from go. I know about the `C.CString` function documented in the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) but as the function I'm calling will already make a copy, I'm trying to avoid the one `Cstring` makes.

Right now, I'm doing this, `s` being a go string

```
 var cs *C.char = (*C.char)( unsafe.Pointer(& []byte(s) [0]))
```

But I get the feeling that the `[]bytes(s)` is making its own copy. Is it possible to just get the `char*` ?

Comment: There is no safe way, and yes, the `[]byte(s)` conversion makes a copy, because strings are immutable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023475/how-do-i-copy-a-go-string-to-a-c-char-via-cgo-in-golang

Comment: I don't mind about an unsafe way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing this enough times that performance is a concern, it would really be advisable to keep the data in a slice to begin with.

If you really want to access to the address of the string, you can use the unsafe package to convert it into a struct matching the string header. Using the `reflect.StringHeader` type:

```
p := unsafe.Pointer((*(*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))).Data)
```

Or using a slice as a proxy, since they both put the data pointer and length integers in the same field locations

```
p := unsafe.Pointer(&(*(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)))[0])
```

Or because the data pointer is first, you could use a `uintptr` alone

```
p := unsafe.Pointer(*(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ps1Py7Ax6QK

None of these ways are guaranteed to work in all cases, or in future versions of Go, and none of the options are going to guarantee a null terminated string.

The best, supported option is to create a shim in the cgo preamble to accept the go string, and convert it to a `*char`. CGO provides access to the following function to do this:

```
const char *_GoStringPtr(_GoString_ s);
```

See the [Go references to C](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C) section in the documentation.

Comment: Not sure if this applies, but [the release notes of 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#cgo) mention the following: «Cgo now supports direct access to Go string values from C. Functions in the C preamble may use the type `_GoString_` to accept a Go string as an argument. C code may call `_GoStringLen` and `_GoStringPtr` for direct access to the contents of the string. A value of type `_GoString_` may be passed in a call to an exported Go function that takes an argument of Go type string.»

Comment: @kostix: yes, I almost forgot that! This directly answers the question to convert the data to a `*char`, but inserting a shim to handle the GoString type would be optimal

Comment: Thanks. To give a bit of a background, this is part of making a bridge between R and go, so sometimes I need to find ways to move go string slices into R character vectors.

Comment: Thanks @kostix, I'd accept that as an answer if you would write it.

Comment: @RomainFrancois thanks, I'm fine with the updated answer by JimB :-)